# AJAX - my simple ajax request does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently learning how to use Ajax but i already have a problem :

1 HTML :

```
<body>
<form>

    Nom d'utilisateur : <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var don=$('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'test.php',
        type:'post',
        data:don,
        success: function(html){
            alert(html);
        }

    });
});
```

});

PHP :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
    $response="yep";
}
else{
    $response="nope";
}

echo $response;
```

?>

As you can see, it is really simple. But it drives me crazy, i didn't understand why i always have the response "nope". 
Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: Because you need to specify the value of the key "username" like this`data: {username : don}`

Comment: Oh you are right ! I can now see in the XHR network the key "username" and it perfectly works ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP requires you to submit `key=value` constructs to properly build $_POST/$_GET with. No key, no value. You haven't provided a key, just a value.

Try

```
data: {"username":don}
```

instead. Or have your PHP script read the raw POST data via `php://input`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending a string. You need to send a JSON object:

```
var don = {"username" : $('#username').val()};
```

jQuery will turn this into a string and send it (I'm assuming, otherwise you need to `JSON.stringify` it), and then you'll need to call `json_decode` on it server-side before you query it.

If you want to continue using your current serverside code, you need to use a `GET` request and submit to `url: "test.php?username="+encodeURIComponent($('#username').val())` and then check the `_GET` variable on PHP side.